# C# WPF transparent window with a border

Tags: c#, wpf, border, transparency

I would like to make a simple application which is transparent but retains the 'normal' borders, close button, minimize and maximize button.

I know how to make the window transparent using the standard

```
<Window
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent">
</Window>
```

but this removes the borders and top right buttons. I read this thread,

[Transparent window with a border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580400/transparent-window-with-a-border)

which sort of gives solution, but really, I just want to be able to keep the standard borders that would be there if I didn't make the window transparent. The means I can move the window, resize, close, etc... Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I threw together a quick `TransparencyConverter` class [based on this tutorial on Microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748975.aspx) you can use for this purpose:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    class TransparencyConverter
    {
        private readonly Window _window;

        public TransparencyConverter(Window window)
        {
            _window = window;
        }

        public void MakeTransparent()
        {
            var mainWindowPtr = new WindowInteropHelper(_window).Handle;
            var mainWindowSrc = HwndSource.FromHwnd(mainWindowPtr);
            if (mainWindowSrc != null)
                if (mainWindowSrc.CompositionTarget != null)
                    mainWindowSrc.CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);

            var margins = new Margins
            {
                cxLeftWidth = 0,
                cxRightWidth = Convert.ToInt32(_window.Width) * Convert.ToInt32(_window.Width),
                cyTopHeight = 0,
                cyBottomHeight = Convert.ToInt32(_window.Height) * Convert.ToInt32(_window.Height)
            };

            if (mainWindowSrc != null) DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(mainWindowSrc.Handle, ref margins);
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Margins
        {
            public int cxLeftWidth;
            public int cxRightWidth;
            public int cyTopHeight;
            public int cyBottomHeight;
        }

        [DllImport("DwmApi.dll")]
        public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hwnd, ref Margins pMarInset);
    }
}
```

Once you have this in, add the Transparent Background attribute to your XAML and subscribe to the Window_Loaded event and call the MakeTransparent method:

```
<Window etc etc Background="Transparent" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var transparencyConverter = new TransparencyConverter(this);
    transparencyConverter.MakeTransparent();
}
```

A screenshot is below:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Almost working.Looks like it works in window 7 but not in window 8. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @StefanVasiljevic Don't think you're going to have much luck on 8, the above code uses Aero which doesn't exist on Windows 8 sadly

Comment: @JMK That is to bad. I always liked the aero in Win 7. Hopefully Microsoft will reconsider putting it back.

Comment: There is a typo in the name of the class itself: TransparencyConverter would be the right name, and not TransparancyConverter!

Comment: @DavideCannizzo Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would first look at the (a)lpha setting in the rgb(a) color of the background color.
The alpha setting sets the opacity of the object color.

Although, I notice that as I'm posting this, there is another post before mine that looks more concise and would probably be more appropriate for you.