# How to make running WPF application window transparent?

Tags: wpf, windows

I have a piece of AutoHotKey script that allows me to set transparency on an active window but it does not work with WPF application like Powershell ISE.

Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: As is stated in the question I need to do that on a running WPF app like Powershell ISE.

Answer (score 12):

Set this in Window element

```
 AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent"
```

Comment: How do I set this on a running WPF app?

Comment: You cannot change AllowTransparency and WindowStyle during running, set them at the beginning and then in particular time change background to transparent.

Comment: How do I set them at beginning of running Powershell ISE?

Answer (score 1):

Hi WPF is based on Direct3D, and is a bit different from win32 and forms which is based on GDI/GDI+.

In WPF you do this in your xaml([see example by maximus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443091/2285592)) or create your own window style.

[There is a post here on how you should do this in WPF.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21461482/2285592)

[Another slightly related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9580660/2285592)

A style :

```
<Style TargetType="Window" x:Key="TransparentWindowStyle">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>         
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency=" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

Skip the x:Key and it will be applied to all windows or you have to place in app.xaml or a place where it is shared, and apply it to the window.  A bit overkill for just 3 properties, but handy if you are going to do other changes, that should be applied to multiple windows.

Hope it helps,

Stian

Comment: Where is the XAML for Powershell ISE?